# ZF2 Creating Sub Directories To Better Manage Files Associated With Each View

Tags: file, service, zend-framework2, structure

I am beginning to program a Member area for my web site.  I've created a Member module.  Since I have plans for many sections within the Member area I've created a series of sub directories within the Member module to contain the groups of files relevant to each menu option the user will see.  I am wanting to use the sub directories as a form of organization.

I am presently receiving the error:

```
Zend\Form\FormElementManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Member\Form\NextPasswordChange
```

I haven't been able to figure out if ZF2 is accessing the files within the sub directories or if I have missed a very simple error.  I am wondering if I am causing ZF2 not to work since I am not sticking with the default file structure.

The actual files for the "NextPasswordChange" View are stored in these directories:

```
./Member/src/Member/Form/Member/NextPasswordChange.php
./Member/src/Member/Form/Member/Factory/NextPasswordChangeFactory.php
./Member/src/Member/Service/Form/NextPasswordChange.php
./Member/src/Member/Service/Form/Factory/NextPasswordChangeFactory.php
./Member/src/Member/Service/Form/NextPasswordChangeInterface.php
./Member/src/Member/InputFilter/Member/NextPasswordChange.php
```

How do I get ZF2 to accept my file structure?

I've created the following entries in module.config.php for NextPasswordChange :

```
'controllers'     => [
    'factories' => [
        'Member\Controller\Member' => 'Member\Controller\Factory\MemberControllerFactory',
    ]
],

'form_elements'   => [
    'factories'  => [
        'Member\Form\Member\NextPasswordChange' => 'Member\Form\Member\Factory\NextPasswordChangeFactory',
    ],
],

'input_filters'   => [
    'invokables' => [
        'Member\InputFilter\Member\NextPasswordChange' => 'Member\InputFilter\Member\NextPasswordChange',
    ]
],
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'Member\Service\Member' => 'Member\Service\Factory\MemberFactory',
        'Member\Service\Form\NextPasswordChange' => 'Member\Service\Form\Factory\NextPasswordChangeFactory',
    ]
],
```

My MemberControllerFactory.php looks like this

```
namespace Member\Controller\Factory;

use Member\Controller\MemberController;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

/**
 * Class MemberControllerFactory
 *
 * @package Member\Controller\Factory
 */
class MemberControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     *
     * @return MemberController
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        /**
         * @var \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait $serviceLocator
         */
        $sl = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();

        /**
         * @var \Member\Form\NextPasswordChange $formNextPasswordChange
         */
        $formNextPasswordChange = $sl->get('FormElementManager')
                        ->get('Member\Form\NextPasswordChange');

        /**
         * @var \Member\Service\Member $serviceMember
         */
        $serviceMember = $sl->get('Member\Service\Member');

        /**
         * @var \Member\Service\NextPasswordChange $serviceNextPasswordChange
         */
        $serviceNextPasswordChange = $sl->get('Member\Service\NextPasswordChange');


        return new MemberController(
            $formNextPasswordChange,
            $serviceMember,
            $serviceNextPasswordChange
        );
    }
}
```

The corresponding section within MemberController.php looks like:

```
namespace Member\Controller;

use Member\Form\NextPasswordChange as FormNextPasswordChange;
use Member\Service\Member as ServiceMember;
use Member\Service\NextPasswordChange as ServiceNextPasswordChange;
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

/**
 * Class MemberController
 *
 * @package Member\Controller
 *
 * @method Request getRequest()
 */
class MemberController extends AbstractActionController
{
    /**
     * @var FormNextPasswordChange $formNextPasswordChange
     */
    private $formNextPasswordChange;

    /**
     * @var ServiceMember $serviceMember
     */
    private $serviceMember;

    /**
     * @var ServiceNextPasswordChange $serviceNextPasswordChange
     */
    private $serviceNextPasswordChange;

    /**
     * @param FormNextPasswordChange    $formNextPasswordChange
     * @param ServiceMember             $serviceMember
     * @param ServiceNextPasswordChange $serviceNextPasswordChange
     */
    public function __construct(
        FormNextPasswordChange $formNextPasswordChange,
        ServiceMember $serviceMember,
        ServiceNextPasswordChange $serviceNextPasswordChange
    )
    {
        $this->formNextPasswordChange = $formNextPasswordChange;

        $this->serviceMember = $serviceMember;

        $this->serviceNextPasswordChange = $serviceNextPasswordChange;
    }
```

Based on the error I'm receiving I also want to include NextPasswordChange form files:

NextPasswordChangeFactory.php

```
namespace Member\Service\Factory;

use Member\Service\NextPasswordChange;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

/**
 * Class NextPasswordChangeFactory
 *
 * @package Member\Service\Factory
 */
class NextPasswordChangeFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     *
     * @return NextPasswordChange
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        /**
         * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager
         */
        $entityManager = $serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

        /**
         * @var \OTFunction\Service\Ipaddress $functionIpaddress
         */
        $functionIpaddress = $serviceLocator->get('OTFunction\Service\Ipaddress');

        /**
         * @var \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator $translator
         */
        $translator = $serviceLocator->get('translator');

        return new NextPasswordChange
        (
            $entityManager,
            $functionIpaddress,
            $translator
        );
    }
}
```

NextPasswordChange.php

```
namespace Member\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;
use OTFunction\Service\Ipaddress as FunctionIpaddress;
use Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator;
use Zend\Session\Container;

/**
 * Class NextPasswordChange
 *
 * @package Member\Service
 */
class NextPasswordChange implements NextPasswordChangeInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @var FunctionIpaddress $functionIpaddress
     */
    private $functionIpaddress;

    /**
     * @var Translator $translator
     */
    private $translator;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager     $entityManager
     * @param FunctionIpaddress $functionIpaddress
     * @param Translator        $translator
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityManager $entityManager,
        FunctionIpaddress $functionIpaddress,
        Translator $translator
    ) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;

        $this->functionIpaddress = $functionIpaddress;

        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    /**
     * accountUpdate
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws \PDOException
     */
    public function accountUpdate(array $params )
    {
        try {

            // Database query to process the form goes here

        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            $this->entityManager->rollback();

            throw $e;
        }
    }

}
```

NextPasswordChangeInterface.php

```
namespace Member\Service;

/**
 * Interface NextPasswordChangeInterface
 *
 * @package Member\Service
 */
interface NextPasswordChangeInterface
{
    /**
     * accountUpdate
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws \PDOException
     */
    public function accountUpdate(array $params );

}
```

I've tried including the additional "Member" sub directory in the references to NextPasswordChange.  When this didn't work I removed it.  I program using PHP Storm.  PHP Storm identifies the Classes contained in the sub directories.  I don't know if ZF2 is following suit.  I am unsure of how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service locator declarations don't match your actual file / namespace structure :

In your `MemberControllerFactory`, you're fetching an instance of `Member\Form\NextPasswordChange`:

```
$formNextPasswordChange = $sl->get('FormElementManager')
                        ->get('Member\Form\NextPasswordChange');
```

Yet your service locator only contains an factory entry for `Member\Form\Member\NextPasswordChange` (notice the additional `Member` namespace):

```
'form_elements'   => [
    'factories'  => [
        'Member\Form\Member\NextPasswordChange' => 'Member\Form\Member\Factory\NextPasswordChangeFactory',
    ],
],
```

Now, when trying to locate `Member\Form\NextPasswordChange`, the service locator cannot find it in this definition and throws this error. 
The names of the instances you're trying to fetch really have to match the keys defined in the service locator configuration.

Second, the factory you are refering to does not exist either in the namespace you provided.

In essence, the service locator is only a `key -> class` lookup, where the key is the name of the service you use for fetching and the value is the class or factory it resolves to. If the key is not defined or the resolved class does not exist, the service locator has no way of knowing what you had in mind.

PHPStorm on the other hand can resolve this class because it does not look at the service locator to load class instances but knows all classes by looking at the file system.

I higly recommend to spend some learning time on how the service locator operates. While it is fairly complex to begin with, the basic mode of operation is actual quite simple:

- Look if the passed name exists as a key in the configuration
- Return the class or use the factory specified for the key's value.